# Facebook SDK getUser() method returns 0 after successful authorization

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently changed my host and noticed that Facebook login is no longer working. It is not throwing any errors, but it's simply not working.

My code:
[Tested with the given example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/)

My workflow:

1. User clicks on the login button (getLoginUrl() method).
2. Facebook authorization window pops up
3. User accepts it and gets redirected back to my page with ?code=..&state=..
4. getUser() returns 0, but it should return the users ID

I tried googling for answers. This is what I tried:

1. To change the getCode() method -> _REQUEST problem
2. Turn on/off cookies

Is there anything else I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try following, add the JS code below the page where you are doing authentication

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
            {
                FB.init
                ({
                    appId   : 'your fb app id',
                    status  : true, // check login status
                    cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    xfbml   : true, // parse XFBML
                    oauth   : true
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function()
                {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            };

          (function()
          {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
</script>
```

Make sure you add a div with id = "fb-root" within the HTML and closed that, best practice is to add that above your JS code as above.

Then use the PHP script to generate the login button and add the following code on the top of your page so that when the page reloads the code gets executed

```
require_once 'src/facebook.php'; //include the facebook php sdk
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',    //app id
    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // app secret
));

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem. My site with the broken login : http://hmworship.com/en/

Comment: I Just tried login to your site with FB and got a blank page perhaps you are working to fix something, but could you please check your app settings "Client OAuth Login" is set to Yes then "App Center Listed Platforms" is set to "Yes" ?

Comment: "Client OAuth Login" is set to "enabled", but where can I find "App Center Listed Platforms"?

Comment: Its under application details tab

Comment: Also many users have similar situation on nginx server where the the Lib is not able to get the query string properly, you may need to check on this. Also make sure that your library contains the file fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt. here is the lib https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src

And finally in app settings app->details->configure app center permissions Auth Token Parameter is set to Query string

Comment: Tried all of the things you suggested, but none of them seem to fix this problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44502/discussion-between-abhik-chakraborty-and-matss-jnis-boltis)